# Elasticsearch not creating defaultly 5 shards

Tags: elasticsearch

I wanted to ask a question about Elasticsearch making 5 shards in each index by default. Well for some reason this is not the case for me. I was wondering whether it was an error on my side (even though I didn't make any changes to the custom template) or this is no longer a case (no longer 5 shards defaultly for each index)? I didn't find anything in documentation or in internet about it. I know I can change this by running:

```
PUT _template/default
{
"index_patterns": ["*"],
"order": -1,
"settings": {
  "number_of_shards": "5",
 "number_of_replicas": "1"
}
}
```

however this is not my point I just wanted to learn what is current way of working for Elasticsearch.

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the 7.x version, the default number of primary shard in each index is 1, as mentioned here in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#_static_index_settings)

Before the 7.x version, the default number of primary shared for each index were 5

You can refer to the breaking changes of the elasticsearch 7.0.0 version [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/breaking-changes-7.0.html#breaking_70_indices_changes)

> Index creation no longer defaults to five shards Previous versions of
> Elasticsearch defaulted to creating five shards per index. Starting
> with 7.0.0, the default is now one shard per index.

Comment: Thank you very much I must have missed that.

Comment: Sure thing! I was going to do it earlier but you answered so quick that it was unavailable for me to accept :D